# Enforce the compiler to pass a method into another method in c# by showing error

Tags: c#

I am having a service class which contains a method `GetSalespersonsAsync()`. It will create an object for Data Service and calls a method `dataService.GetSalesPersonsAsync()`. Here I need all the Data Service method calls to pass to another method in the service `InitiateApiCallAsync()`.

```
public async Task<List<Salesperson>> GetSalespersonsAsync()
{
    using (var dataService = DataServiceFactory.CreateDataService())
    {
        var response = await InitiateApiCallAsync(dataService.GetSalesPersonsAsync());
        return response?.code == 0 ? response.data : null;
    }
}
```

```
public async Task<TResponse> InitiateApiCallAsync<TResponse>(Task<TResponse> dataService) where TResponse : BaseAPIResponse
{
    TResponse response = await dataService;
    await BaseProcess(response);   // async process of some internal actions with response from the method call
    return response;
}
```

If any of the data service methods failed to pass into the `InitiateApiCallAsync()` method, then the compiler need to show compile time error, so that it won't be missed to pass into it in future.

Kindly provide the possible solution to handle this to avoid missing this behavior in future.

Comment: _Or_ runtime error? Your compiler does not show _runtime_ errors, only compile-time errors. Since you say you are okay with runtime errors, check the state of your response instance and throw a descriptive exception if it wasn't set up properly. If you want to prevent these errors to happen for consumers at all, you have to handle these things internally and remove them from the public surface.

Comment: @Ray Thanks for notifying the mistake. I need to show compile time error here if it missed to pass to InitiateApiCallAsync().